# Is this proof of the Cancellation Law for multiplication of real numbers correct?

Tags: proof-verification, real-numbers

The original statement is:

> If $ab = ac$ and $a \neq 0$, then $b = c$. (In particular, this shows that the number 1 of Axiom 4 is unique.)

By Axiom 6, we know that exists a real number y such that $y*a = 1$. Since multiplications are uniquely defined, we know that $y*(a*b) = y*(a*c)$. By the Axiom 2, we can rewrite it as $(y*a)*b = (y*a)*c$ but we do know that $y*a=1$ so we have $1*b = 1*c$. By Axiom 4, we know that $1*b = b$ and $1*c =c$ so we have $b = c$

---

**Axiom 2**: $x + (y + z) = (x + y) + z$ and $x(yz) = (xy)z$.

**Axiom 4**: There exist two distinct real numbers, which
we denote by 0 and 1, such that for every real x we have $x + 0 = x$ and $1*x = x$.

**Axiom 6**: For every real number $x \neq 0$ there is a real
number y such that $x*y = 1$.

Comment: " Since multiplications are uniquely defined"  I'm not entirely sure what you mean by that and that's probably not the best wording for what you are trying to say.  But otherwise your proof is absolutely correct and quite well done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your proof looks fine. :)

---

<sup>I'm posting this CW answer so that users who **confidently** concur have something to vote on, 
and so this question doesn't stagnate in the [Unanswered Questions Queue](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=unanswered).</sup>